# How can i order by last update row

Tags: php

I have one Sql Query to get all the informations from my table.

I created an list using an foreach.

And i want to order this list, by the last updated row.

Like this

```
       $query - "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY last_updated_row";
//call Query here
```

And when i updated a certain row, i want to put this row on the top of the list

I heard about time_stamp, can i use time_stamp for that?

how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your using MySQL your table needs to be like this

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  last_updated_row TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

That will give the row a create time stamp and update it on each update statement which effects the row

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use just about any date/datetime/timestamp column in a table to sort by if needed. The only catch is you need to actually *have* it in the table.

Any of the above will allow sorts by ascending/descending order, but need to be maintained when inserting/updating a row.

Assuming you have the following structure:

```
table - someTable
id    someVale    updateTime
1       54634       ......
2       65138       ......
3       94141       ......
4       84351       ......
```

It doesn't matter what type of column `updateTime` is - whether it is a date, a datetime, a timestamp, a simple `order by updateTime` will work.

But you need to make sure that each insert/update you make to that row updates the column so that the sort will be true.